# How to build Eclipse RCP only for specific OS

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, rcp, tycho

I have set up an Eclipse RCP build with maven and tycho. Currently there are build results for several OS's that I don't need. How can I restrict It only to be build for a speciffic OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about tycho, however I know there is a separate plugin to configure the platforms.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <environments>
        <environment>
            <os>win32</os>
            <ws>win32</ws>
            <arch>x86</arch>
            </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
        </environments>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

I did find a few links in Google as well.  Googling "tycho target platform" will probably find you more.

[http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTycho/article.html]
[http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Plugins_Explained#target-platform-configuration]